# In r, I am trying to mutate a year month column which is in "2001.01" format to 2001 Jan

Tags: r, zoo

```
mutate(mtest = as.yearmon(as.numeric(myear), "%y %b"))
```

But no luck with it. Can someone help me out. Thanks in-advance.

Comment: I guess your format argument is not correct. Try `as.yearmon("2000.01", "%Y.%m")`

Comment: It working. Thank You @markus

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon("2001.01", "%Y.%m")
[1] "Jan 2001"
```

Comment: `"%M"` stands for "Minute as decimal number (00–59)", see `?strptime`

Comment: this is `%m`, not `%M`

Answer (score 1):

Lubridate is really helpful for dates.

```
d <- c('2001.01.01','2002.12.12')
noise <- c(1,2)
df <- cbind(d,noise)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$d <- ymd(df$d)
df$m <- months(as.Date(df$d))
df$y <- year(as.Date(df$d))
df <-  unite(df, date, c(y,m),remove=TRUE, sep=" ")
```

This will land you with a column containing 'month_name year'. The only thing I didn't bother with is abbreviated month names.

Comment: This is good. If you want to abbreviate the month, you can add the argument  `label = TRUE` to `months()`. Also since the original data is in "year.month" format, instead of` `ymd()` you could use `parse_data_time(df$d, orders = "ym")` since there is no day. I also think `unite` comes from tidyr and not lubridate.

Comment: Ah yes you're correct about tidyr. Thank you, I got `ymd()` from lubridate.